# Use a non-RTTI interface in RTTI code

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm

I need to be able to derive a class from non-RTTI code into an RTTI code project. I'm using LLVM which disables RTTI in their code. I know I can't do typeinfo and dynamic_cast on their code, that's fine, but it appears derivation also doesn't work. Somehow GCC believes it needs the typeinfo for the base class, though it won't exist. I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter'
```

How can I use the base class a from a no-rtti library in a rtti project?  *I am assuming the RTTI is the problem since I can't think of what else it would be.*

Comment: It might be related to differences between no rtti and rtti just for exceptions.

Comment: LLVM also disables exceptions and this class is not used in any throw/catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You have to recompile LLVM with RTTI in this case.

Comment: Yes, recompiling with RTTI is what I did. It's easy enough that it's not worth investigating another solution.